# Wildcard in Command Prompt

Tags: wildcard, command-prompt

I understand how to use the wildcards `*`? in CMD, however I am not sure of how far I can take them. Can I use a wildcard to look for multiple folders and multiple files?

Ex. `move /-y C:\4folders\*\*.txt C:\combinedfolders\`

Would this run? Or is there an issue with having multiple wildcards? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Ex. move /-y C:\4folders\*\*.txt C:\combinedfolders\

Comment: nope, won't work - at least not in any version of CMD I'm aware of.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.